# Access to unencrypted WAN traffic

Tags: ip

A basic plain-text unencrypted TCP connection is setup as follows:

Network Client LAN <----> Network Modem <--> ISP <--> Remote Server

The network Modem only has a single wired user, and nobody can sniff any LAN packets.

TCP packets are generated on the Network Client underneath the lan. The network modem sends packets to the ISP and then to a remote server.

**Assume**

1. The Local and Remote server is completely trusted. No LAN traffic can be sniffed on either end.
2. The ISP itself is trusted or are allowed to see the traffic, and they are not compromised.

Is there any way for hackers to see the unencrypted packets as they travel throughout the WAN? They know both the source IP and destination IP address. Can they sniff this traffic?

Answer (score 6):

Any attacker who has access to some equipment (cable, router, ... ) between the network modem and the remote server might be able to access the data, i.e. it should not be a problem for government agencies. Note that an attacker might also change the path of the traffic with [BGP hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP_hijacking) in order to be in path of the traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  If the client connects to the server using an insecure protocol (such as HTTP instead of HTTPS), then the data sent back and forth between the client and the remote server is contained in plaintext in the packets.  So, anyone at any of the carriers between the ISP and the remote server that has access to the routers that these packets are routed through could potentially have access to the plaintext data going back and forth between the client and the remote server.